How can I show $ m_a(bc - a^2) + m_b(ca - b^2) + m_c(ab - c^2) \geq 0. $ in a triangle
$
\text{Problem 3: Let } ABC \text{ be a triangle with } BC = a, CA = b, AB = c. \text{ Let } m_a, m_b, m_c \text{ be the lengths of the medians drawn to the sides } BC, CA \text{ and } AB, \text{ respectively. Prove that}
$
$$
m_a(bc - a^2) + m_b(ca - b^2) + m_c(ab - c^2) \geq 0.
$$
I have tried to implement Erdos-Mordell inequality. Letting the centroid be $O$. $OA, OB$ and $OC$ can be expressed in $\dfrac{2m_a}3,\dfrac{2m_b}3,\dfrac{2m_c}3$. But I don't know how to deal with the term $bc-a^2$.

Welcome to MathSE! What have you tried?

I've tried to implement Erdos-Mordell inequality. Letting the centroid be $O$. $OA,OB$ and $OC$ can be expressed in $\frac{2m_a}{3}, \frac{2m_b}{3}, \frac{2m_c}{3}$. But i don't know how to deal with the term $bc-a^2$

I could find some duplicates using Approach Zero.

I could find a same question on MSE here
